# Ruby: Converting Hexadecimal Strings to Hexadecimal NON-string (edited)

Tags: ruby, string, integer, hex, libgosu

Lately, I've been struggling to search online for ways to convert hexadecimal strings into hexadecimal actuals. As an example, `"0xffffffff" -> 0xffffffff`. After loading the JSON file (which cannot store hexadecimal directly), the stored integer value, `4294967295`, was successfully converted back to `"0xffffffff"` by using the following example code:

```
hex_str = "0x" << 4294967295.to_s(16) #--> "0xffffffff"
```

The real frustration is that I cannot seem to find a Ruby way to recreate that hexadecimal value without being a `String` datatype... I really hope I'm not overlooking anything. My reason for the use of non-string hexadecimals is to utilize them for Gosu-coloring notation. I do not want to use Gosu's `Color` class (inputting rgb values `[255, 255, 255]`) as it slows the performance drastically when many rectangular `quad_draw()` objects are generated in-game (it went down to about `42 fps` from `60 fps` when `600` rects were drawn). The program did run at `60 fps` when I hard coded in the hexadecimal actuals (not of string datatypes), so I'm confident that using these values in that format are the way to go. This is something I'm looking for:

```
hex_int = hex_str.some_function_to_hex #--> 0xffffffff
```

Could you share a way that could convert `4294967295` to `0xffffffff` directly?

Comment: I really don't understand the question considering that `4294967295` and `0xffffffff` are the same integer value. Ruby merely displays integers in base 10; `#--> 0xffffffff` is no different than `#--> 4294967295`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. There is no such thing as a "hexadecimal integer" or a "decimal integer" or a "binary integer" or a "ternary integer" or whatever other base integer. An integer is an integer. Period. The base is a property of the *notation*, not the number. In other words, the term "hexadecimal integer" is non-sensical. It is not even wrong, it simply makes no sense. You can have a hexadecimal *representation* of an integer, but that is purely a property of the *textual representation*. In Ruby, the data type for text is the `String`, so "hexadecimal" *only* makes sense for strings.

Comment: Gosu also uses `_` to separate the alpha value from the RGB values, e.g. `0xff_ffffff`. Just like the hex notation, the `_` is purely cosmetic. See the docs for [number literals](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Numbers).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you for the explanation - what you said makes perfect sense. I'm not sure why I would get down-voted, but if you say that hexadecimal only makes as a string, then why is Ruby allowing me to write out `0xffffffff` without quotes, as if it is an integer (or some other datatype)? I get that 4294967295 is the same as 0xffffffff, but why is non-string 0xffffffff a thing? And it does make a difference when I tried using "0xffffffff" as a String - Gosu::Color.new("0xffffffff") does not work, but Gosu::Color.new(0xffffffff) does. Can you explain that?

Comment: @Stefan I am aware of that alternative. It is great for readability!

Comment: _"as if it is an integer"_ – it _is_ an integer. Ruby allows you to enter number literals in various bases, because in some contexts (see the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Numbers)!), hex, octal or binary notation are more common or more readable than decimal. You can enter `255` as `255` or as `0xff`, `0o377`, `0b11111111`, `0d255`, or `2_5_5`. It's entirely up to you. All of them refer to the very same integer: `255`

Comment: My apologies to all who were confused with my question. I think I now have gained the lore that 0xffffffff is indeed an integer from reading the Ruby docs. However, the Gosu docs should have made it more clear that the color value should not be limited to the format of hexadecimal and that integers like 4294967295 work as well... perhaps they assumed that people reading the docs already understand 0xffffffff as an integer, which I didn't know at the time. Thanks for all of the help, and kudos to @Chandan for giving me a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly pass integer to `Gosu::Color.new` to create color

```rb
3.0.0 :002 > Gosu::Color.new(4294967295)
 => #<Gosu::Color:ARGB=0xff_ffffff>
```

Or `Gosu::Color.argb`

```rb
3.0.0 :003 > Gosu::Color.argb(4294967295)
 => #<Gosu::Color:ARGB=0xff_ffffff>
```

Comment: Wait, so does that mean I can use it in this context?

`@image.draw(x, y, z_order, 1.0, 1.0, 4294967295, :additive) #replacing 0xffffffff or Gosu::Color`

Comment: @TaylorMcDowell Yes you can also confirm from the [doc](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gosu/gosu/master/Gosu/Image#draw-instance_method).